# A Vandermonde like identity for binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

The Vandermonde identity is given by

$
\left(\begin{matrix}
m + n \\
j
\end{matrix}\right) = \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^k \left(\begin{matrix}
m \\
j
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
n \\
k-j
\end{matrix}\right)$

or equivalently

$
\left(\begin{matrix}
m + n \\
r+s
\end{matrix}\right) = \displaystyle\sum_j \left(\begin{matrix}
m \\
r+j
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
n \\
s-j
\end{matrix}\right)$ where $j$ runs through both negative and positive integers.

I would like to know if there is any equivalent Vandermonde identity for the following sum, and if so, what would be the best way to derive it?

$
\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\min\{s,m-r\}} \left(\begin{matrix}
m \\
r+j
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
n \\
s-j
\end{matrix}\right)$

Thanks for any help in advance!